# Mustache undefined

Tags: javascript, mustache

I had a working web page using javascript and mustache that has stopped working probably because Mustache is undefined.

Any ideas what I should do to get this working again?

Here's the beginning of the page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Solar_BTU_Log Web Access</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/raw/master/mustache.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SBL_JavaScript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SBL_Styles.css"></link> 

  </head>
<body>

  <div id="divA">


      <p><b>Site: {{site}}</b></p>
      <p><b>Time: {{time}}</b></p>
      <p><b>Date: {{date}}</b></p>
      <p><b>Pump: {{pump_state}}</b></p>
      <p><b>Collector Temp: {{collector_0}}</b></p>
      <p><b>Storage Temp: {{storage_0}}</b></p>
      <p><b>BTUs Collected Today: {{btus_3}}</b></p>
      <p><b>BTUs Collected Overall: {{btus_0}}</b></p>
      <p><b>Ouside Temp: {{waux4_0}}</b></p>


    <p><b>Probe Table</b></p>
    {{{ptable}}}

    <p><b>Statistics Table</b></p>
    {{{stable}}}

  </div>

  <p>Here are some links...</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="SBL_Probes.htm">Raw Probe Data</a></li>
    <li><a href="SBL_Stats.htm">Raw Statistics Data</a></li>
    <li><a href="SBL_Doc.htm">SBL Web Documentation</a></li>
  </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

  // Initialization, make sure Mustache is available

  LogOn();
  Log("<b>Start</b>");

  function Fail (txt)
  {
    document.getElementById("divA").innerHTML = 
    "<p>" + txt + ", processing terminated</p><p>Press reload to try again</p>";
    exit;
  }

  if(typeof Mustache=="undefined")
  {
    Log("Mustache undefined");
    Fail("Critical component Mustache unavailable");
  }
```

The diagnostic "Critical componenet Mustache unavailable" is produced.

Comment: Have you tried to include the mustache resource in your project directory? It might be failing to fetch the resource from that external src.

Comment: yes, I tried it with the mustache.js in the same file as the page.

Comment: @ChrisHaugen is right. The Github URL you used for Mustache does not allow you to embed it in a page. Go to https://rawgit.com/ , paste that URL in there, and it will give you a proper URL to use.

Comment: @ChrisHaugen:  That did the trick; thank you very much.  If you or blex wish to post that as an answer I'd be delighted to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the Github resource is not loading properly into your project as an asset.

My recommendation would be to include the actual Mustache asset in your project folder, that way you are certain that the asset is always available to your project.

@blex also made a good point, you can use the resource rawgit.com to convert the Github link to a use able url to import your asset.